# How to automate detection of half-frame images using Epson V550/V600?

Tags: film, scanning, epson

I have several strips of 35mm negatives shot with an Olympus PenD, which is a half-frame camera. When scanning, I find manually selecting frames one-by-one is time consuming for 72 images per roll.

Is there a way I can tell Epson V550/V600 scanner software to detect all the frames?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we've seen similar questions before. Since there does not seem to be an obvious solution, they may have been automatically closed due to inactivity (and thus not searchable).

Comment: Duplicate? https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/102497/on-the-epson-perfection-v500-how-does-one-scan-half-frame-negatives-efficiently

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not possible with the native scanner software, since it seems you didn't find an appropriate setting that does what you want. Some third-party scanner software, such as [SilverFast](https://www.silverfast.com/highlights/autoborder/en.html) or [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/), might be able to do it. I haven't used either, so you will have to research them or try demo versions to see if they fit your needs.

If your scanner software is able to automatically detect full frames, you could write a script that uses ImageMagick to cut the results in half after capture. It wouldn't be fancy – no auto detection of image boundaries – but it would make further work with the images somewhat easier by splitting them into separate files. On Mac or Linux, it would look something like this:

```
for i in *.tif ; do
   convert "$i" -gravity left -crop 55%x100% "${i%.tif}-left.tif"
   convert "$i" -gravity right -crop 55%x100% "${i%.tif}-right.tif"
done
```

Comment: VueScan does it! It's super expensive though...